# Restarting of Docker Containers within AWS ECS autometically

Tags: connection, docker, amazon-web-services, rds

I have deployed a Spring Boot Application in AWS ECS Docker container. My application is communicating with AWS MYSQL RDS using JPA.

Application is deploying successfully.

But after sometime, application is throwing following error in CloudWatch log and restating the container again.

```
2019-05-03 11:04:36.270 INFO 1 --- [nio-8192-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-05-03 11:04:36.270 INFO 1 --- [nio-8192-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-05-03 11:04:36.282 INFO 1 --- [nio-8192-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Completed initialization in 12 ms
2019-05-03 11:05:14.706 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-4] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-05-03 11:05:14.708 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-05-03 11:05:14.716 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-05-03 11:05:14.720 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Both Cluster EC2 and MySQL RDS are in same VPC

and my RDS is open to internet can be accessed from amywhere.

I am not able to understand why HikariPool is shutting down after some time constantly. looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your connection pool, its closing due to shutting down of Executor service see [here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956801/shutting-down-executorservice-applicationtaskexecutor)